# iOS jailbroken device: intercept and block the swipe from down gesture to call the Control Center

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, control-center

What I need is to intercept and block the swipe from down gesture to call the Control Center while the user is using an app (he isn't in the springboard) to replace them with a new action. When the user is in the springboard everything it must be as default so he must be able to open the control center.

What's method I must hook to intercept the control center call under my condition (the user is not in the springboard)?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From browsing iOS 6 headers, it seems [SBPanGestureRecognizer](https://github.com/caughtinflux/iOS-6-SpringBoard-Headers/blob/master/SBPanGestureRecognizer.h) inherits from [SBGestureRecognizer.](https://github.com/caughtinflux/iOS-6-SpringBoard-Headers/blob/master/SBGestureRecognizer.h) SBGestureRecognizer has these methods:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(struct __SBGestureContext *)arg1;
- (void)touchesMoved:(struct __SBGestureContext *)arg1;
- (void)touchesBegan:(struct __SBGestureContext *)arg1;
```

I'd look into hooking one of those.

Comment: I've edit my answer with more details about. Anyway thanks for your answer.